# How to create isolated workspace in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I got a top model like Project, and many sub models like Store, Task, Bug, TestCase.

```py
class Project(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Bug(models.model):
    project = models.ForeighKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Story(models.model):
    project = models.ForeighKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Task(models.model):
    project = models.ForeighKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I want to seprate project as isolated workspace in admin.

when I select a project, store the current project id, and when I create sub model objects or view change list, all object is belong to this project.